# How to display text images from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the obscure title but I have no clue how to actually ask this. Anyway, I'm coding a hangman assignment and have the hangmen in a list:

```
hangmen=[
'''____________________ 
       |  /
       | /
       |/
       |
       |
       |
   ____|________________''',

'''____________________     
       |  /     |
       | /     (_)
       |/     
       |      
       |       
       |      
   ____|________________''',

'''____________________     
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/       |
      |        | 
      |       
      |      
   ___|________________''',

'''____________________
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/      /|\
      |      / | \
      |
      |
   ___|________________''',

'''____________________
      |  /     |
      | /     (_)
      |/      /|\
      |      / | \
      |       / \
      |      /   \
   ___|________________''']
```

When I refer to one of the items in the list:

```
hangmen[1]
```

I get this:

```
____________________     \n           |  /     |\n           | /     (_)\n           
|/     \n           |      \n           |       \n           |      \n       
____|________________'
```

What can I do to get the hanging body representation?

Comment: It appears as though your console is printing the "official" string representation (such as `repr()`) of the given list element (which will include `\n`, etc.), whereas the "informal" string representation (using `str()`) prints fine on my console. See @Prune's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python's interactive mode, merely listing the item name displays its raw value.  If you wan the formatting characters interpreted, you need to push it through a rendering routing, such as `print`:

```
>>> print(hangmen[1])
____________________     
       |  /     |
       | /     (_)
       |/     
       |      
       |       
       |      
   ____|________________
```

If you want to know more, start by looking up the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

```
hangmen=[
 r'''____________________ 
        |  /
        | /
        |/
        |
        |
        |
    ____|________________''',

r'''____________________     
        |  /     |
        | /     (_)
        |/        
        |      
        |       
        |      
    ____|________________''',

r'''____________________     
        |  /     |
        | /     (_)
        |/       |
        |        | 
        |       
        |      
     ___|________________''',

 r'''____________________
        |  /     |
        | /     (_)
        |/      /|\
        |      / | \
        |
        |
     ___|________________''',

 r'''____________________
        |  /     |
        | /     (_)
        |/      /|\
        |      / | \
        |       / \
        |      /   \
     ___|________________''']
```

Note the use of **raw string** (`r''' string''').
  Now you can print each element of the list like this.

```
    print(hangmen[1])
    # or, to print each element
    for item in hangmen:
        print(item)
```